# Binding to an enumeration in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, enumeration

I have a UserControl that I built that has properties which are defined in the xaml like this:

```
<Repeater:JointScoringGrid x:Name="PIPLeftErosionsRepeater" 
            TabName="PIP" 
            Header="Erosion"
            ControlNamePrefix="Left"
            ScoringType="Erosions">
```

Then, in my code behind I have logic centered around the `ScoringType`.  Currently I'm checking which `ScoringType` the Grid is by evaluating the string (i.e. `ScoringType.ToUpper().Equals("EROSIONS")` ) which works, but it's not as clean as I'd like it to be.  What I would rather do is use an enumeration, but use the name in the xaml rather than the numeric value (e.g. I want to use something like `ScoringType="Enum.Erosions"` instead of `ScoringType="0"` to make the xaml more readable).  Can this be accomplished?

Comment: @H.B. RIght you are.  I should read more closely next time.

Comment: Btw, `TuUpper` string comparisons are *evil*, use [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) with a case-insensitive comparison type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the type of the property to the enum type, it should automatically parse the string to the enum value. (e.g. [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx)`="Stretch"` works, just an enum property)

Comment: @user564636: You're welcome, glad it helped. Even WPF can even be simple at times :)

Answer (score 1):

Define scoring type as dependency property of your Enum type. Then you can bind it in xaml like

ScoringType={x:Static YourEnumType.Erosions}